# DynamoDB not storing in proper ISO 8601 for composite key

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am following one of AWS's best practices to minimize GSIs by using a status + date as a composite sort key (see https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/advanced-design-patterns-for-amazon-dynamodb-dat403-reinvent-2017). However, the dates are not being written to the table in the proper order.

Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TicTacToe.Phase2.html, "So if all status prefixes are the same (for example, IN_PROGRESS), the ISO format used for the date part will have items sorted from oldest to the newest."

That's not what I am seeing. I basically ripped their code to get started and I'm not getting those results.

Here's an example of what I use to write to the table:

```
table = dynamodb.Table('Aware')

        now = str(datetime.now())
        statusPinDate = "ACTIVE_" + now
        updateDate = now
        entryTags = entry + '|' + learning + '|' + challenge + '|' + tags

        response = table.put_item(
                Item={
                    'PK': awarenessId,
                    'SK': statusPinDate,
                    'GSI1PK': userId,
                    'GSI1SK': entryTags,
                    'Awareness': {
                        'UpdateDate': updateDate,
                        'Feeling': feeling
                    }
                }

                )
```

Here's what I am seeing results-wise when I run a query:

```
"PK (S)","SK (S)"
"AWR-7b2733f9-2a33-4c50-9d24-f45663fdf006","ACTIVE_2019-09-05 21:43:39.623838"
"AWR-08ca298e-06d0-4d7e-bf75-069b14bc23d9","ACTIVE_2019-09-02 20:36:01.656237"
"AWR-2f6ab2a7-9552-4b89-8e7b-4d006c95ec7d","ACTIVE_2019-09-04 19:57:20.179045"
"AWR-30917553-206f-45c6-8cfd-9a45423b8816","ACTIVE_2019-09-03 07:18:10.391391"
"AWR-3a5cd84c-d21f-4f50-81f9-5ebead289ed4","ACTIVE_2019-09-05 07:11:16.909416"
"AWR-4a3acab1-3fd0-4ca6-8939-4c756f196879","ACTIVE_2019-09-04 07:42:41.815524"
"AWR-5c1bc2a9-079d-4e37-b30d-2c39913b7075","ACTIVE_2019-09-07 07:31:50.917259"
"AWR-8e50a379-d22d-4789-ac81-66bb83fc6453","ACTIVE_2019-09-06 07:45:39.578668"
"AWR-bfd4605f-d64a-47ad-a56c-064df7422bc3","ACTIVE_2019-09-03 22:14:40.850001"
"AWR-e0b61340-8371-4357-b3f8-1894cada6db0","ACTIVE_2019-09-03 15:59:53.137947"
"AWR-f5459ee7-27e0-44ab-bb59-596867223eca","ACTIVE_2019-09-06 22:40:26.657986"
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it too much to expect AWS to store in the right order? Maybe there is an elegant way to manipulate the query to grab these records in order. I don't want to create another GSI but it's looking that way.

Comment: can you please post your query code? also, are using a dynamodb query or a scan? also, IIUC, you are querying the GSI, right? so can you please post what attributes are used a partition + sort key of the GSI?

Answer (score 1):

The sort key only sorts the values within each partition key -- not independently.  All the partition keys in your example are different, so the sort keys are shown with no ordering, which is correct/expected.

This strategy is only useful when there are multiple rows per partition key, either in the base table or a secondary index.